# Array with colon not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created an array but i want to add a colon to it to display it in a select option field.

My code:

```
var listInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
var item;
var listItemInfo = '';
var i = 0;
var index = 0;
var aanvragersarray = new Array();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

    item = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

    //Aanvragerslijst ophalen en in array stoppen
    if (item.get_item("Aanvrager")) {
         var aanvragerID = item.get_item("ID");
         var aanvrager = item.get_item("Aanvrager");
         aanvragerslijst.push([aanvragerID, aanvrager]);
         var row = { ID: aanvragerID, naam: aanvrager }
         aanvragerslijst.push(row);

    }

    i++;
}
```

I need to have something like this:

```
//Select field aanmaken met aanvragers
// Add the list of numbers to the drop down here
selectValues = { 1: "james", 2: "mark" };
```

Is this possible with javascript to create such array with a loop?

Answer (score 0):

The array of options you want to create is actually an associative array. That means you can just declare and populate it straight away using the index/key and the value:

```
var selectList = {};
selectList[1] = "james";
selectList[2] = "mark";
console.log(selectList); // prints Object { 1="james", 2="mark"}
```

Declare `aanvragersarray` as `{}` and populate it inside the loop.

**UPDATE**

According to the [update](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23246607/2) the OP has edited into @hsz's answer, the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3N79/) shows it is actually working.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have something stranges with my array. It adds empty options to the list. see below =>

```
<select id="LKAanvrager"><option value="0"></option><option value="1"></option><option value="2">Wendy</option><option value="3"></option><option value="4">Benny</option><option value="5"></option><option value="6">Kris</option></select>
```

This is my function

```
function onLoadItemsSuccess(sender, args) {
var listInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
var item;
var listItemInfo = '';
var i = 0;
var index = 0;

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

    item = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

    //Aanvragerslijst ophalen en in array stoppen
    if (item.get_item("Aanvrager")) {
        var aanvragerID = item.get_item("ID");
        var aanvrager = item.get_item("Aanvrager");
        aanvragerslijst[aanvragerID] = aanvrager;
    }

    i++;
}


//Select field aanmaken met aanvragers

 $.each(aanvragerslijst, function (key, value) {
     $('#LKAanvrager').append($("<option/>", {
         value: key,
         text: value
     }));
});
```

}

I need my own ids as value because they match with the form i'm adding to the list.

Anyone a suggestion ?

Answer (score -1):

To fill select option field, use json syntax

Below is syntax for json array to store your values

```
var selectedValues=[{1:"james"},{2:"mark"}]
```